# Expected response code 250 but got code "550" (Trying to send mail with Swiftmail)

Tags: php, swiftmailer

The error message I get is:
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550-Sender (uid: 8, user: domain.com, sender: 550 no-reply@domain.com) over ratelimit

I've got the right connection details, (I've set it to localhost) because If I change that I get connection refused. I've not had this error before but googling it doesnt seem to give me a solid answer.  So i've come here.

The code is fine, I am convinvced it is something wrong with the server, because its the same code to send an email I use on all my other domains.

Code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/swiftmail/swift_required.php");          
$transport  = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SWIFT_IP, SWIFT_PORT)->setUsername(SWIFT_USERNAME) ->setPassword(SWIFT_PASSWORD);
$mailer     = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);    

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance("[ContactForm]") 
        ->setFrom(array("no-reply@domain.com"=>"No Reply"))
        ->setTo(array("my-email@outlook.com")) 
        ->setBody($mailbody, 'text/html');
$sentmessage = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Could you share the code as a sanity check?

Comment: `Sender over ratelimit` - isn't that the problem?

Comment: @raina77ow yes it is, but I don't have a clue what it means or how to solve it.